# Angular2: Work correctly with XML REST response

Tags: xml, web-services, angular

I'm developing an Angular2 application. This app, call a WebService that return an Xml response. 
My Service class that call webservice has this method:

```
callPost() {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, '&param=value'
  , { headers: this.getHeaders() }).map(res => res);
}
```

where getHeaders function is

```
 private getHeaders() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return headers;
 }
```

I call function inside my component class in this way:

```
this.myService.callPost().subscribe(
  resp => this.resp = resp,
  error => alert(error),
  () => console.log(this.resp.text())
)
```

As i've noticed, xml response is inside 
    this.resp.text()

Now i need to extract data from that xml (tag with attributes and value between tags), and i don't know how to do (i've stard developing in Angular2 yesterday). 
Can someone explane me how to procede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th easiest route is to add an external module that converts your incoming XML back to JSON. This is a good option: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js.